# Change the python executable that Django 1.7 loads

Tags: python, django, anaconda

I am building an app on Google Compute Engine using Django 1.7 and Python 2.7 within a Debian environment.

To get the mpl_toolkit library to work I have had to install Anaconda and its various modules within that environment, thereby over-riding the default "out-the-box" Bitnami setup.

I am currently unable to get the live server to run python from the Anaconda directory (/home/beastflow/anaconda2/bin/python) as it needs to.

Indeed, when I load the page I get the following line as part of the debug message:

Python Executable:  /opt/bitnami/python/bin/python

What do I have to change in order to get Django to point to /home/beastflow/anaconda2/bin/python ?

Comment: I have isolated the problem, I think, to an issue with mod_wsg, but am still unable to get it to point to the correct python distribution. Someone please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found an answer (which avoids having to rebuild mod_wsgi). If you're using Bitnami, you can get python to load from a different path by changing /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/envvars by adding a PATH line as follows (for example):

```
PATH=/home/beastflow/anaconda2/envs/django17/bin/:$PATH 
export PATH
```

Then restart the apache server:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
```